# Function is undefined after being defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPFGa/2/) highlights my issue.
It is mimicking some functionality I have where an Object is defined and sent to the Page via socket.io.

I have a setInterval function checking if `Pots` is a function, and when it is I fire an Event.  During that Event I try to instantiate a new instance of `Pots` only to be told that it is undefined.

The code:

```
var Pots;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var timerId = 0;
    var otherTimer = 0;

    otherTimer = setInterval(function() { console.log("Creating"); Pots = function() {}; }, 5000);

    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Checking");

        if (_.isFunction(Pots)) {
            console.log(Pots);
            clearInterval(timerId);
            clearInterval(otherTimer);

            var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
            evt.initEvent('ObjectsAvailable', true, true);
            document.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }

    }, 1000);

});

document.addEventListener('ObjectsAvailable', function(e) {
    console.log(Pots);
    var Pots = new Pots();
});
```

***EDIT***
Posted this comment below:
I should point out that `Pots` is actually a Backbonejs Collection with this declaration: `var Pots = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Pot});`.  The reason I did the event is because there IS a time when "Pots" isn't set (probably before the browser has loaded the file with Pots declared).  The jsFiddle was just to simulate that time exists.  In my actual code "otherTimer" doesn't exist and Pots IS eventually a Function but when I try to use it during the `ObjectsAvailable` event, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set the global variable "Pots" to any value, so it remains undefined.

The "ObjectsAvailable" handler looks like it attempts to set it, but

1. It tries to call "Pots()" to do so, so that won't work, and
2. It declares a local variable "Pots" too, so that hides the global one.

Another note: the fiddle is set up with the code to be run in the window "load" handler, so the "ready" handler is redundant.

Comment: +1, 2 is right, when he does var Pots he hides the global one

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes so it's sort-of double wrong. Even without the `var` it wouldn't work.

Comment: I should point out that `Pots` is actually a Backbonejs Collection with this declaration: `var Pots = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Pot});`.  The reason I did the event is because there IS a time when "Pots" isn't set (probably before the browser has loaded the file with Pots declared).  The jsFiddle was just to simulate that time exists.  In my actual code "otherTimer" doesn't exist and Pots IS eventually a Function but when I try to use it during the `ObjectsAvailable` event, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it may be that in some code, but in the question the global variable `Pots` was declared without any initialization. It's sort-of a waste of time to post an example that does not accurately represent the actual code, especially in such a critical way. In any case, the `var` in your handler function is the main problem.

Comment: AH!  I see now, yes the problem was the `var` in the Event Handler.  Thank you!